# issues with miredot-plugin

Tags: java, documentation, maven-plugin, dropwizard

I am trying to run `mvn clean install` on a dropwizard project and bound miredot documentation  in the maven lifecycle. It has some REST endpoints where i am trying to generate some REST documentation using miredot-plugin [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.qmino/miredot-plugin ]. the pom.xml's relevant section looks like this:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.qmino</groupId>
                <artifactId>miredot-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-RC1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>restdoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <organizationId>1234567890</organizationId>
                    <restModel>
                        <restFramework>
                            <name>jax-rs</name>
                        </restFramework>
                    </restModel>
                    <output>
                        <html></html>
                    </output>
                    <!-- insert other configuration here (optional) -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and here is how the logs look like when ran `mvn clean install`. I am only posting the relevant and last section of the log below:

```
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] ?[1m--- ?[0;32mmiredot-plugin:2.0-RC1:restdoc?[m ?[1m(default)?[m @ ?[36mmulti-family-service?[0;1m ---?[m
[?[1;33mWARNING?[m] Miredot is unable to document the status codes of rest interfaces, unless a statusCodes-block is specified in pom.xml
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Building reflective model of API and reading annotations...
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=false, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=false, maxAge=60, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1
, mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=false, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=false, maxAge=60, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1
, mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=false, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
[?[1;34mINFO?[m] Unknown annotation on service method: skipped @io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControl(immutable=false, noCache=true, maxAge=-1, noTransform=true, proxyRevalidate=false, isPrivate=false, sharedMaxAge=-1,
 mustRevalidate=false, sharedMaxAgeUnit=SECONDS, noStore=true, maxAgeUnit=SECONDS)
```

at the last line of the log, it hangs indefinitely and dies. I have tried upgrading the miredot plugin but of no help. I also tried disabling all firewalls on my machine suspecting it is not able to talk to any extrnal links but still no help. Any pointers?